# How to access this array?

Tags: javascript

This is simple but I have no idea where I am going wrong. Could you please let me know how I use the returned data. I have been calling 
`favorites[0].name` but I get no response.

```
    person.favourites=function(){
       return [
           {
             'name'= 'Gmail',
             'link'= 'www.gmail.com'
           },
           {
              'name': 'Facebook',
              'link': 'www.facebook.com'
           }
       ];
    };
```

Comment: Could you show your call to favourites method?

Comment: You are using `favorites[0].name` while accessing whereas it's defined as `person.favourites`. Or is it a typo? Can you show more code?

Comment: Did you called `favOUrites[0].name` or `favOrites[0].name` ?

Comment: There is no JSON in your example, just a JavaScript array.

Comment: Property assignment to the first object is incorrect, it should be done with ":" operator, not with "=".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *call* your function, using `person.favourites()`, instead of referencing it with `person.favourites`:

```
console.log(person.favourites()[0].name);
```

Answer (score 4):

`favorites` is not an array, but a function that returns an array. You need to invoke it:

```
var x = person.favourites();
alert(x[0].name) // gmail
alert(x[1].link) // www.facebook.com
```

You could also change your definition:

```
person.favourites = [
    {
        'name'= 'Gmail',
        'link'= 'www.gmail.com'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Facebook',
        'link': 'www.facebook.com'
    }
];
```

In that way you'd be able to access `person.favourites[0].name`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, i just needed to invoke as you showed, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create your `person.favourites` with an annonymous function you could invoke it during the assignment:

```
person.favourites=(function(){
       return [
           {
             'name': 'Gmail',
             'link': 'www.gmail.com'
           },
           {
              'name': 'Facebook',
              'link': 'www.facebook.com'
           }
       ];
    })();
```